# How to verify that the input text allows the first and second digits to be only letters

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms

I need to validate a input text, the first 2 digits only letters after adding a hyphen and finally 5 numerical digits.

format example: aa-12345

now i have

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCodigoTopografo" onkeydown="test(this)"   runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

function test(e) {
        console.log(e);

        switch (e.value.length) {

            case 0:
                if (e.value)
                e.value = e.value.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '');
                break;

            case 1:
                e.value = e.value.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, ''); 
                break;
            case 2:
               e.value = e.value.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
                break;
            case 3:
                e.value = e.value.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
              
                break;
        }


       
        
       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current method is trying to *replace* stuff with regex. Instead, use regex to *verify* your input string is in the correct format.

This regex assumes the letters must be lower case. You can change `[a-z]` to `[A-z]` if you allow upper or lower case.

```js
function test() {
  var textboxContent = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var passed = /^[a-z]{2}-\d{5}$/.test(textboxContent);

  if (passed) {
    document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Passed!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Failed!";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Type here!" oninput="test()" />
<p id="result"></p>
```

An explanation of the regex:

```
^     Match the start of the input. Used so that you don't match part way along the input
[a-z] Match a lowercase letter...
{2}   ...2 times (you could do "[a-z][a-z]" instead)
-     Match hyphen
\d    Match a digit...
{5}   ...5 times (you could do "\d\d\d\d\d" instead)
$     Match the end of the input. Used so that you don't match part way along the input
```